# UIButton image not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I created a custom UICollectionViewCell with a button

.h file:

```
@interface MyCVC: UICollectionViewCell
-(void)setButtonImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

.m file:

```
@interface MyCVC()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
@end

@implementation MyCVC
-(void)setButtonImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [self.myButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

However calling setImage on MyCVC does not cause the image to appear, instead the button is filled with the Tint color.
Also I noticed that if I set the button image in the interface builder to any image before running setImage is later working as expected,
What is the problem ?

Comment: Did you change Image and try?

Comment: Your button is called `myButton` but you're setting the image of something named `buttonImage`.  (???)

Comment: Obviously its a mistake I made while simplifying the code, Please consider the button name to be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you should do like this**

```
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.buttonImage setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

should be

```
[self.myButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```